# PHP if statement, variable equal to display, hide if not

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I'm struggling with making an if statement where if a variable value (the page title) equals 'loan' a field is div is hidden but if the variable equals any other value the div is displayed.

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($product['custom_fields'][1]['value'])){ ?>
        <div class="content-2">
            <p><strong><?= $product['custom_fields'][1]['field']?></strong>
            <br /><?= $product['custom_fields'][1]['value']?></p>
        </div> 
    <?php } 
?>
```

I have created the following code to show the hidden div (on on the 'loan' pages) but can't seem to successfully incorporate that code into the if statement for the custom field variables above.

```
<?php
    if(false !== stripos ($product_list_data['name'], 'loan')){ 
        echo "<div class='content-bottom'><p><strong>" . $product['custom_fields'][1]['field'] . "</strong>
<br />" . $product['custom_fields'][1]['value'] . "</p></div>";
    } 
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this fixes the problem, but could you remove `false !==` from the if statement?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say above, what exactly is the problem that you are facing
and secondly i think that you have syntax error
try this:
<?php if (condition): ?>
html code to run if condition is true
<?php else: ?>
html code to run if condition is false
<?php endif ?>

Comment: @AmmarAjmal His syntax is not the problem.

Comment: Please use: [PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures;](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). In each case, the basic form of the alternate syntax is to change the __opening brace_ to a __colon (:)_ and the _closing brace_ to _`endif` etc._

Answer (score 2):

```
$display = 'block';
if (strpos($product_list_data['name'], 'loan') !== false) {
    $display = 'none';
}

<div class="content-2" style="display:<?php echo $display; ?>;">
<p><strong><?= $product['custom_fields'][1]['field']?></strong>
<br /><?= $product['custom_fields'][1]['value']?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You could even change `<?php echo $display; ?>` to `<?=$display ?>` as PHP template engine supports that

Comment: short tag has some drawbacks. Please view this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use